# How to fetch get all console log , error , warning in text file if i click i a button

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

I have a project which produces some warning, logs, error if anything goes wrong so I want to give the user a button where they can click and download console.log and save in text file. I can use extension I want to do in JavaScript and jQuery any of these ways.

I want to get all this in a text file

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create replacements for console.log, console.error, etc. and append the messages in a variable:

```
var log = "";
var myConsole = {};
myConsole.log = function(txt) {
  log += txt + "\n";
  console.log(txt);
}
```

Then you can create a downlodable file whose content is the log variable. Check [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server) for different ideas of how to do this.

Comment: bt their are multiple files . should i have to do this in complete application and also i have api code which i can't modify , i have to fetch the current console data

Answer (score 2):

two steps are required to answer your question:

1. read console.log output into a variable
2. saving the variable to a text file

## step 1 - listen console logging events

it can by done by replacing the console object with self-made interface:

```
var consoleText = ""
// define a new console
window.console = (function(console){
    return {
        log: function(text){
            console.log(text);
            consoleText += text;
        },
        info: function (text) {
            console.info(text);
            consoleText += text;
        },
        warn: function (text) {
            console.warn(text);
            consoleText += text;
        },
        error: function (text) {
            console.error(text);
            consoleText += text;
        }
    };
}(window.console));
```

and for unhandled exceptions:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
    consoleText += event.message;
})
```

## step 2 - save the log file

based on DevonTaig answer in [Writing html form data to a txt file without the use of a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870876/writing-html-form-data-to-a-txt-file-without-the-use-of-a-webserver):

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
  document.body.appendChild(pom);
  pom.click();
  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}

download("log.txt", consoleText)
```

Comment: should i create separate js file for step 1 and add it main.js

Comment: it's not necessary, but I strongly recommend separating it to a file separate from your main program

Answer (score 0):

Found out there is library written by someone [here](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js).

Added some code to demo:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./FileSaver.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Log download</h1>
<script>
    // Store logs in memory for writing to file ater.
    let logList = [];

    function downloadLogs() {
    var blob = new Blob([logList.toString()], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "logFile.log");
    }

    function createLogMessage(){
        logList.push('log message....');
    }
</script>
    <button type="button" onclick="downloadLogs()">Create Log!</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="createLogMessage()">Write Log!</button>
</body>
</html>
```