# how does this stop criterion (for-loop) work?

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a way to take input from my HTML form to my javascript code without a server inbetween and found this post on Stackoverflow:
[How to use HTML forms without a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051143/how-to-use-html-forms-without-a-server)

There, the first answer included the following link to a code example on js.fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wG8K4/1/

```js
function updateBackgroundColor(color) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function displayFormContents(someForm) {
 var out = '';
    for (var i=0, el; el = someForm.elements[i]; i++) {
        if (el.name) {
            out += el.name + ' = ' + el.value + '\n';
        }
    }
 alert(out);
}
```

```html
<form>
 <select name='gender' onchange='updateBackgroundColor(this.value);return false;'>
 <option value=''>Select A Gender</option>
 <option value='blue'>Male</option>
 <option value='pink'>Female</option>
 </select><br/>
 type your nickname: <input type='text' name='nickname' /><br />
 <input type='button' value='Display Form Contents' onclick='displayFormContents(this.form);return false;' />
 </form>
```

I've tried out this approach in my own code and it works. However, I don't understand how this stop criterion works Oo

```js
el = someForm.elements[i]
```

does this stop criterion kick in when the index hits a value where there is no corresponding array element anymore (the array thus probably returning something like undefined/false)? I guess so, because I could also observe that the loop iterates just 2 times (index 0 and 1). However, I have no way of verifying this assumption and thats why I wanted to ask here.

Comment: It's a horrible practice. Don't use this kind of loop.

Comment: yeah now that the "length" approach was mentioned I saw that its unnecessary to take this route and rearranged my code to the light side :D

Comment: Or even just `for (const el of someForm.elements) {`, the modern variation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`el = undefined` is `undefined` which is a **falsy** value that stops the loop.

That means that the loop stops as soon as `i` is bigger or equal to `someForm.elements.length` (when `someForm.elements[i]` is `undefined`).

Comment: Only when i reaches over the length of the array, ofc

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is a bad show-off code example? I advise to not code this way because it takes a lot of time to understand.