# How do you collect data from a local HTML file with a form and store it locally(so that there is no need to worry about servers)?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

Here is the problem: I want to make an HTML form in a local file(as a sort of UI), and then save data from that form into a JSON file(preferably, other file types are OK as well). I assume a JavaScript is needed in the HTML to do something with the form. From another thread([How to use HTML forms without a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051143/how-to-use-html-forms-without-a-server)), I heard about a $_GET function, but it was not clearly explained and didn't work when I copied the example code into an HTML editor. It was also missing the explanation for how to write it to a file, probably because JS on the web can't write a file on your client computer. In this scenario, however, my goal is to have the entire thing stay local. This was one of the solutions presented by the other thread:

```html
<script language="javascript">
function $_GET(q,s) {
    s = s ? s : window.location.search;
    var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i');
    return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;
} 

var usersName = $_GET('username');
if(typeof(usersName)!='undefined'){
    document.write('<h1>Hi there, '+usersName+'</h1>');
}

</script>
<form>
     <input type="text" name="username" />
     <input type="submit" value="Say my name" />
</form>
```

However, this threw an error when I tried to use it(if you hit run snippet it should show you the error) , and again, doesn't provide how to write the data to a file. Is there a simple way to collect the data from the form and save it to a file, with no services like wordpress, no servers, entirely locally? Let me know if there is more information I could be providing

Comment: Since you don't run it on local server, use local storage api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage . Another solution can be by file api but it need to actively load and save the external file. check this: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles//

Comment: This was something I looked into, but the problem with that was that at least the Mozilla web API assumes there is a server involved. My goal is to only use the HTML as a UI for an entirely local program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a much easier way. While I was previously insistent on there not being a server, if you make a "server"(in quotes to make it less intimidating,because nowadays that stuff is handled for you), it is far easier. Essentially, in the same directory as your HTML, make a .php file. PHP is the most common language to run servers. In HTML, set the action attribute of your form to the name of your php file, and the method attribute to POST if you want to send data to the "server". Now, once you set it up, the php script will run automatically whenever the form is submitted(no event-based programming needed). Start your php file with `?php` and end it with `?>`. All variables in php start with `$`.
the `$_POST` variable is a built in variable that contains an associative array(like a dictionary, a list with user-defined keys), where the keys are the ids of each input element in the form that was posted.
**HOW TO SET UP PHP:** In terminal(on mac, at least)(make sure the root directory in terminal is the directory of your html and php files), enter the following: `php -S localhost:8000`. This is only accessible from computers on your network, so you are not opening a port to the entire internet. Then, in a browser, go to localhost:8000 to see you html file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the value from your inputs. Using onClick of a button, call that button download button. Which will get values from the input field and then structure it in json format and then using html download tag download the file...

Comment: Thanks! This is a good answer, but it doesn't mention exactly how that onClick function would get the information from the forms, which is one of the key issues I was having. I assume the snippet in my question should help as an example of a get method, but what exactly is causing it to error(I assume something to do with it being from 2009)

Comment: What do you think of this as a way to get data from a form? `<script type ="text/javascript">
 function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
    set s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test.txt", True);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input1.value);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input2.value);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input3.value);
    s.Close();
 }
  </script>`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this. The code snippet I put in my question had one small error(other than being unclear to those inexperienced in JS like myself). I found the error, and it was probably caused by that code snippet being out of date. Essentially, the answer is that when you submit the form, the URL(or filepath if local) gets appended with a url encoded argument showing the data entered(e.g. index.html?username=testUserName). Here is the code snippet, with comments showing what the annoyingly complex script does(or at least it worked on my computer):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
        <form>
             <input type="text" name="username" />
             <input type="submit" value="Say my name" />
        </form>
        <script language="javascript">
            function $_GET(q,s) {
                s = s ? s : window.location.search;//This line says that if the queryString parameter is given, it stays, if not, it is set as the url or file path of the current html doc
                var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i');//this line creates a pattern of characters that is url encoded to get attributes from the url. All the stuff after q+ basically decides whether the argument is the beginning of the url args, and so whether to add a ? or an &
                return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;//the first part replaces the url starter ? with an &, then returns all strings that match that, such that if all works, index 0 will be the url argument starting with &, and index 1 will be the actual input value. If it is undefined, it is returned as undefined. If not, the method returns the value that was entered 
            } 
            
            var usersName = $_GET('username');
            if(typeof(usersName)!='undefined'){
                document.write('<h1>Hi there, '+usersName+'</h1>');
            }
            
            </script>
</body>
```